# Can I buy a 5-day flexi twin pass at the Frankfurt airport or train station and use it that day?

Tags: trains, tickets, germany

I've been clicking around the DB Bahn web page looking for information about the Twin flexi pass. I know I can book it online and it will be sent to me, but it will probably arrive after I leave as I am in Taiwan and it could take some time to arrive in Frankfurt.

Can I just wait and get the pass in the airport or at the train station itself in Frankfurt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Deutsche Bahn forum (24th November 2017):

> Is it possible to buy the German Rail Flexi Twin Pass in Germany itself at the train station?
>
> **[DB]:** You can buy the German Rail Twin Pass in the following train station:
> Basel Bad Bf, Hamburg Hbf, Berlin Hbf, Berlin Südkreuz, Berlin Zoologischer Garten, Hannover Hbf, Heidelberg Hbf, Kaiserslautern Hbf, Bonn Hbf, Köln Hbf, Köln/Bonn Flughafen, Düsseldorf Hbf, Düsseldorf Flughafen, Dresden Hbf, Leipzig Hbf, München Hbf, München Flughafen, Nürnberg Hbf, Frankfurt (M) Hbf, Frankfurt (M) Flughafen, Stuttgart Hbf und Wiesbaden Hbf.

https://community.bahn.de/questions/1503991-german-rail-twin-pass-flexi